# Why does my batch file not continue execution after running Diskpart in WinPE?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd, winpe

I am trying to create a batch file to run in WinPE. I would like to know how to run a large batch file which calls diskpart then exits and continues running the batch file. When I call diskpart it just exits after running the diskpart part. I know how to run a diskpart batch file.

```
 @echo off
diskpart /s createparts.txt
```

Here is the sample diskpart batch file I am using to create partitions. I wish to run copyimg.bat at the end of the file to continue the automated processing which is going to copy an image to the newly partitioned drive.

```
select disk 0 
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY size=100
format quick fs=ntfs label="OS"
assign letter="c"
active 
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY 
format quick fs=ntfs 
assign letter=d 
exit
call copyimg.bat
```

I know I am calling exit before calling copyimg.bat, however I need to exit from diskpart before running other non diskpart related scripts.

Comment: What happens if you move `call copyimg.bat` to the last line of the `diskpart /s createparts.txt` script?

Comment: If I try and call `copyimg.bat` from a parent batch file after `diskpart /s createparts.txt` , It does not call the rest of the script.

Comment: It should as long as `copyimg.bat` doesn't contain `exit` without the `/b` switch, and you be sure not to exclude `call` from `call copyimg.bat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix batch commands and diskpart commands in the same file.  You already have two files, but you're putting the extra batch commands in the wrong place.

The batch file should look like this:

```
@echo off
diskpart /s createparts.txt
call copyimg.bat
```

The diskpart file `createparts.txt` should look like this:

```
select disk 0 
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY size=100
format quick fs=ntfs label="OS"
assign letter="c"
active 
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY 
format quick fs=ntfs 
assign letter=d 
exit
```

When diskpart reaches the end of its instructions, it will exit and the batch processor will resume from the point where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your lines from "select disk 0" through "exit" in a file like DiskPartCmds.txt and then replace those lines in your bat file with this line.

```
DiskPart.exe < DiskPartCmds.txt
```

Comment: How is that different from `diskpart /s createparts.txt`? From `diskpart /?` -> `/s <script> - Use a DiskPart script.`

Comment: @DavidPostill, should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for another script. After call it instead of continue and execute the following commands, it was stopping. I solved it with **cmd /C**, as example:

```
cmd /C my_script_file.bat
another_command
more_stuff_here
```